# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\USER\family\Desktop\index\https-app\sever\ssl\ssl\server.crt

Tags: node.js

I'm trying setup an HTTPS server with NodeJS and Express ,but I'm getting the following error :
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDFsV.jpg)

And this is my code:

```js
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const https =require('https')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const directoryToServe = 'client'
const port = 3443

app.use('./',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)))

const httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.crt')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.key'))
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
.listen(port, function()
{
  console.log(`Serving the ${directoryToServe}/directory at https://localhost:${port}`)})
```

And this is where my files are saved :
[Screenshot of location of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFnN.jpg)

Comment: Didn't you note `ssl\ssl` in your cmd output ? 
Compare that with your directory structure. Try to access the mentioned file by putting the address in the explorer address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the`ssl`in`fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.crt'))` in between `__dirname` and `server.crt`

`fs` will be looking for another `ssl` directory which doesn't exist as `...https-app\server\ssl\ssl\server.crt` and `...https-app\server\ssl\ssl\server.key`

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const https =require('https')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const directoryToServe = 'client'
const port = 3443

app.use('./',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)))

const httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'server.crt')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'server.key'))
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
.listen(port, function()
{
  console.log(`Serving the ${directoryToServe}/directory at https://localhost:${port}`)})
```

Answer (score 0):

you was able to add the symbol `(\\)`
Exp:  `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + "\\\private.key"));`